# SocketTimeout Exception in Elastic Search, But No timeout at API Level

Tags: java, elasticsearch, bulk

I am trying to do a bulk update (sync) to Elastic Search.
The Bulk Update to Elastic Search is wrapped over a service and other application call that API to Bulk Update which internally calls ES Bulk API.

Application (Client) -> BulkUpdateToES (Wrapper Service) -> esclient.bulk()

Now, esclient.[bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-bulk.html)() is failing with a socket timeout exception.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-44 [ACTIVE]\n\tat org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.timeout(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:387)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:98)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:40)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.timeout(AbstractIODispatch.java:175)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.sessionTimedOut(BaseIOReactor.java:261)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.timeoutCheck(AbstractIOReactor.java:506)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.validate(BaseIOReactor.java:211)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)\n\tat org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)\n\t... 1 more
```

However, the service call seems to not timeout i.e the response from BulkUpdateToES is returned under 1 sec.

I am trying to reproduce the issue and will update the response data once I get it.

However, I could not understand even though the ES is using a sync bulk update. How did the Wrapper API call did not had a timeout issue though ES had a timeout issue.

Comment: Is this issue related to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57109948/sockettimeoutexception-while-retrieving-or-inserting-data-into-elastic-search-by ?