# Indexing a large dataset in elastic search causes java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-223 error

Tags: java, elasticsearch, socket-timeout-exception, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I am indexing a large dataset using Elasticsearch's high level REST client for JAVA. When I say "indexing", I mean creating the index, adding a mapping, adding a lot of data (8 million documents) and then aliasing the index. I notice that this error often causes the indexing to crash. Most often the crash occurs after the index and mapping are created and during the process of adding documents to the index. However, the error sometimes occurs beforehand while creating the index or the mapping.

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on
> connection http-outgoing-223 [ACTIVE]
>
> Occasionally there is a "circuit-breaking" error.

I'm pasting both errors below

I have stepped through my code and see this error does not happen at any consistent location in my code. The error also does not seem to occur when adding a document with any particularly unique values.

I have increased the RAM in my elasticsearch cluster's aws.data.highio.i3 instance from 1GB to 8GB and the issue persists.

Here is the entire stack trace for the socket timeout error...

```
    WARN  [2020-04-19 19:58:05,923] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase: HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@437eff49 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
ERROR [2020-04-19 19:58:41,331] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 1ed68c8eb0476ec6
! java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]
! at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.timeout(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:387)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:92)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.timeout(AbstractIODispatch.java:175)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.sessionTimedOut(BaseIOReactor.java:261)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.timeoutCheck(AbstractIOReactor.java:502)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.validate(BaseIOReactor.java:211)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
! at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
! ... 1 common frames omitted
! Causing: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]
! at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:808)
! at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:248)
! at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:235)
! at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1514)
! at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1484)
! at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1454)
! at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClient.java:871)
! at org.project.core.services.ElasticSearchService.createElasticIndex(ElasticSearchService.java:613)
! at org.project.core.services.ElasticSearchService.reindex(ElasticSearchService.java:726)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
! at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:159)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:50)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617)
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:35)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:47)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:41)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:310)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:264)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:249)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:52)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:717)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:54)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:173)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
! at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Here is the entire stack trace for the circuit breaking error...

```
INFO  [2020-04-19 19:34:09,206] org.project.core.services.ElasticSearchService: Elasticsearch exception [type=circuit_breaking_exception, reason=[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [410582854/391.5mb], which is larger than the limit of [394910105/376.6mb], real usage: [392568768/374.3mb], new bytes reserved: [18014086/17.1mb], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=341/341b, in_flight_requests=18014086/17.1mb, accounting=1124688/1mb]]
ERROR [2020-04-19 19:34:09,223] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 656d425f54800b53
! java.lang.NullPointerException: null
! at org.project.core.services.ElasticSearchService.updateDocuments(ElasticSearchService.java:489)
! at org.project.core.services.ElasticSearchService.addRecordsFromPostgresToElasticIndex(ElasticSearchService.java:684)
! at org.project.core.services.ElasticSearchService.reindex(ElasticSearchService.java:727)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
! at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
! at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:159)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:50)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617)
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:35)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:47)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:41)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:310)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:264)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:249)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:52)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:717)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:54)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:173)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
! at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: can you provide entire stacktrace

Comment: I added the entire stacktrace

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56815933/es-rest-high-level-client-throws-sockettimeoutexception-after-being-idle-for-som where you can specify a larger timeout.  It may help.